# How to extract the certaine data and its file name from multiple excels to .txt format with python

Tags: python, excel, txt

I would like to create the code which extracts the certaine data and its file name from multiple excels to .txt format.
I wrote the code as below, but it shows the all file names in folder to each data in .txt format.
How to extract the each file name..?
My goal is to have the extracted data displayed as "filename" "data from column10" in .txt format.

```
import pathlib
import openpyxl
import os.path
import glob

f = open('data.txt', 'w') 
path = pathlib.Path(r"..\file")


for path_obj in path.glob("*.xlsx"):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path_obj)
    sheetnames = wb.sheetnames
    for sheetname in sheetnames:
         sheet = wb[sheetname]
         for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
            if sheet["A" + str(row)].fill.start_color.index == 'FFFF0000': 

                 file_path = glob.glob(r"C:\\python\\file\*.xlsx")
                 name_list = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0] for file in file_path]
             
                 f.write(str(name_list) + "  ")
                 f.write(str(sheet.cell(row=row, column=10).value))
                 f.write("\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: Looks pretty good so far.  Is there a problem?

Comment: Why the second glob with a [possibly] different path?

Comment: This code would extract all file names in a folder for a single data.
Therefore, I would like this code to display only the filename for one extracted data.
In the case of data extracted from A.xlsx, I would like to display "A.xlsx" "data from colum10" in .txt format and if the data extracted from B.xlsx,it should be displayed "B.xlsx" "data from colum10".　The difference in the path for the second glob does not seem to matter. (It's actually the same.)

Comment: @Jane The paths are potentially different. You have r"..\file" and r"C:\\python\\file\*.xlsx" which are not necessarily the same

Comment: I canged the second path→”file_path = glob.glob(r"..\file\*.xlsx")” but the same result appered, still displaying like  "A.xlsx, B.xlsx" "data drom column10".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if this is what you are looking for. As mentioned by Vlad, I don't believe you need to use glob twice. The `path_obj` already has the file name. So, update you code like below and see if it is what you are looking for...

```
import glob, os
import pathlib
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

f = open('data.txt', 'w')
path = pathlib.Path(r"SampleDir") ##My test dir, you can change it

for path_obj in path.glob("*.xlsx"):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path_obj)
    sheetnames = wb.sheetnames
    for sheetname in sheetnames:
        sheet = wb[sheetname]
        for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
            if sheet["A" + str(row)].fill.start_color.index == 'FFFF0000': 
                #f.write(str(path_obj) + "  ")  ## This will add the file name incl. path
                f.write(os.path.basename(path_obj) + "  ") ## REPLACE for only filename
                f.write(str(sheet.cell(row=row, column=10).value))
                f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: Hi Redox, Thanks again for your help.  I was able to do what I wanted to do. The only thing is that the extracted file name is prefixed with ". .\file\" character comes with the name of the file. Is it possible to omit this and just extract the file name?

Comment: Hi @jane - you can use `basename` for that. I have replaced the line where you write to a file with the new line. Please see the updated code above